# Trying to connect to Redis client running on WSL with Node

Tags: node.js, redis, windows-subsystem-for-linux, wsl-2, node-redis

I am using the node redis package to connect to a redis client running on WSL because I use windows. This is my connection code:

```
const redis = require("redis");

const redisClient = redis.createClient();

redisClient.on("error", (err) => {
  console.error("Error connecting to Redis:", err);
});

redisClient.on("connect", () => {
  console.log("Connected to Redis");
});

module.exports = redisClient;
```

I am running the redis client on WSL.
[image]

When I start my backend server I get no feedback from my redis configuration code. It doesn't say connected or error. But if I log something before the redisClient.on lines it'll show up in the console. I am completely lost.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to call `.connect` after the client has been created as per the example at the [top](https://github.com/redis/node-redis#basic-example) of the [README](https://github.com/redis/node-redis) for Node Redis:

```js
import { createClient } from 'redis';

const client = createClient();

client.on('error', err => console.log('Redis Client Error', err));

await client.connect();
```

Comment: Thank you it worked! I was just watching your youtube video on installing Redis on windows 10 by the way. It was super helpful. Thank you so much!

Comment: Thanks! Glad you liked it!

Answer (score 1):

From [redis package](https://www.npmjs.com/package/redis):

```
import { createClient } from 'redis';

const client = createClient();

client.on('error', err => console.log('Redis Client Error', err));

await client.connect();

await client.set('key', 'value');
const value = await client.get('key');
await client.disconnect();
```

It looks like you didn't add `client.connect();`, so the client is created but connection is never attempted.